# How to fetch and map api response data using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

Sending request to API and get API response in console and that return data will be `object` .

`API RESPONSE:`

Refer Here :[Json API response](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-einstein-yelvj?file=/src/data.json)

Now how to disply data on webpage using axios. Below code shows how to call API

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            key: '10-10-21',
            // Where data will be saved.
            data: [],
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/hgetall_hash?key=${this.state.key}`)
        .then(response => {
                        // Updating the state to trigger a re-render       
            this.setState({data: response.data});
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { key } = this.state
        
        return (
            <center><div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <h2> DATE PICKER</h2><br></br>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="key"
                            value={key}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />                        
                    </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div></center>
        )
    }
}
export default PostForm
```

From this code to to store response in variable and map , display data in Grid view.

Comment: you can use {this.state.data.map(item => {map your item here, don't forget the key}} somewhere in your returned jsx

Comment: also, the <center> tag is deprecated in HTML5 and the <br /> tag is self closing. Finally, your change handler needs to be rebound to "this" in the constructor

Comment: @DovRine can you explain with my code i want to fetch time and video on display

Answer (score 1):

The response will be stored in the data which you have defined inside this.state.

> this.state.data.map((item)=>( {item.time} )) 
> to display is grid you can use display: grid

Comment: But i got some error when i try this

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: `TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function`

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot od the code which is giving you error, I believe there is a syntax error

Comment: https://github.com/Chuttyboy/React_API_call/blob/main/error.png

Comment: I believe where u r updating the data to response.data it is not saving it. Try one thing hardcode the key in the API instead of using this state.key. also check whether u r getting the response back from API

Comment: Comment this for now this.setState({data: response.data}); instead console amd check are u getting the response?